# Error PhpMyAdmin muestra tablas que estaban borradas

Tags: base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Estuve gestionando una DB con `phpmyadmin 4.0.10.14`, y elimine algunas tablas y creé otras. El problema es que las que he eliminado siguen apareciendo como tablas, y si les hago clic me sale el siguiente mensaje:

> 1146 - Table 'example_db.employees' doesn't exist

Como podría solucionar este problema y que las tablas eliminadas no sean visibles en phpmyadmin?

Comment: Ya probaste recargando el panel de navegación?

Comment: ¿Limpiaste la caché?

Comment: [SOLUCIONADO] reinicie el panel de navegación como lo sugirió @j-castro Muchas Gracias

Comment: no probé tu opción @alvaro-montoro